# nodejs/express/ejs render() synchronous

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

```
res.render("index.ejs", {});
```

The above would be fine for simple cases.

How do I make EJS return the processed string as the function's return value?
Make it work like this:

```
res.send(ejs.render("index.ejs", {}));
```

In other words - **I want to nest/chain a few render() calls**, NOT asynchronously.

Express doesn't seem to support this natively, or does it?
And if not, then how would I achieve it directly through EJS?

*If you wonder why I prefer the "bad" way (synchronous) then I got one thing to say: Cache.

The templates are being cached anyway, so I don't mind the first load of the template to be slower (in just a few ms anyway).

This cost of single delay of a time fraction is no cost compared to having to deal with nested async calls to render().*

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass a callback to `res.render` which will be called with the rendered string. This will be done `async` which is the right way to approach this since rendering may require a file read.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { title: 'Title' }, function(err, result) {
    res.render('index2', {foo: 'data'}, function (err, result2) {
      console.log('Render result:');
      console.log(result2);
      res.send(result2); // send rendered HTML back to client
    });
  });
});
```

If you don't like nested callbacks, I would suggest looking at an async library like the aptly names `async`. You can use the waterfall ( https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall ) function to do this:

```
async.waterfall([
  function(done) {
    res.render('index', {title: 'Title'}, done);
  },

  function(result, done) {  // result is the result of the first render
    res.render( result, {foo: 'data'}, done);
  }
], function (err, result) {  // result is the result of the second render
  console.log(result);
  res.send(result);
});
```

Comment: I explicitly asked it to be synchronous. I'm aware of the implications. Please understand that in my case I'm up to render() a file which will render() another file. So it's nested within different files and not functions as your solution suggets. Thanks though.

Comment: If you really want sync, then you'll need to write your own render function. Render functions in `express` require the use of callbacks.

Comment: Hehe I know that much already! Was hoping someone will come up with a solution. Anyway, already wiring up my own function.

Comment: Personally I think that's silly considering you can use the default render with the `async` library to get rid of the nested callbacks. The callbacks aren't just for async, they also provide a mechanism to hand back errors and bail if one occurs. If you do render(ejs(ejs(ejs(...)))) what happens if the second one has a problem?  Withe the `waterfall` approach I can handle all errors in one central location and return the appropriate error to the client.

Comment: you got a point but don't "limit" yourself with these cases. Trust me I know why I want it. Also told it. If you read carefully between the lines you'll see my point.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try ejs.renderFile? its result is an HTML that you can send to the client.

Would be something like

```
res.send(await ejs.renderFile('./path/to/ejs/file.ejs', {}))
```